# How to dynamically show data inside a dynamically added div

Tags: jquery, razor

I am dynamically adding a div inside another div and I am successful in doing it. However, I want to display data inside the dynamically added div in which I am really stuck. Below is the code:

**.js**

```
function GetInfoOnSameActivity(currentElem, priorityObj) {    
        if (priorityObj.UpcomingActivities() != undefined) {
            $.each(priorityObj.UpcomingActivities(), function (i, v) {
            var activityElements = $(currentElem).find('.priority-icon')[i];
            var div = $('<div>').addClass('detail-popup');                
            $(activityElements).append(div);           
                });
    }
  }
```

This above jquery function is called at the load time. The cshtml is as below:

**.cshtml**

```
<div class="priority-icon">                    
                @*<div class="detail-popup">
                    <strong data-bind="text:Title()"></strong>
                    <p data-bind="text:Description()">
                    </p>
                </div>*@
            </div>
```

The code that I have commented in the **.cshtml**, is the class that I am adding dynamically. I now want to add the tag values dynamically inside the class **detail-popup**. Do I need to add and append each tag that I have used in the **.cshtml** inside the dynamically added div to show their value(eg. `<strong>, <p>`)

Comment: you can append multiple tags like `$('.el').append('<div><p><strong></strong></p></div>');`

Comment: Thank you @madalinivascu. It worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append multiple tags like

`$('.el').append('<div><p><strong></strong></p></div>');`